# How recursion works when used twice?

Tags: recursion

```
int func(a,b,c){
    if(a==b)
        return; 
    func(a,c,b); // <-- 1
    func(a,b,c); // <-- 2
}
```

I use this **recursive** function.  I want to know that how the recursions 1 and 2 work? That means when the 2nd recursion starts working, how the interaction is occurred between them?

Comment: This does not look like an example of recursion

Comment: When you debug this, how do you observe it working?  Generally, the way code works is that one statement is executed and then the next statement is executed.  I see no reason why this code would be any different.

Comment: @JamesAMohler: Are you sure about that?  `func()` internally invokes `func()`.  Looks like recursion to me.

Comment: I'm a little confused with your code. Is 1. and 2. an example of calling the code, or are those lines in the function? If those are indeed lines in your function, then you will get a stack overflow error; since you are not altering the variables in any way, and calling them back and forth exponentially, you will crash the program.

Comment: That is a stackoverflow. Literally. Unless `a == b`. 
Even if `a == c` the recursion will never end.

Comment: Change them to print statements. How do they work? There is no difference between calling itself and calling something else. The last statement calls exactly the same as it was originally called. That means it will never terminate.

Answer (score 1):

It would be impossible to tell what the result would be without example input values.

- func(3,3,5);    // would return directly  (a==b)
- func(1,2,3);    // would cause an infinite loop (a != b != c)
- func(3,2,3);    // would recurs once  (a==c)

func ***is*** a recursion however since it does call itself (func() calls func() within itself).

But is has big problems since it can easily loop forever.

Unless it can be proven that it is a finite loop, a proper recursion func would also count its recursions and exit on an arbitrary high number.

Answer (score 0):

Call#2 is never going to be executed. Call#1 will always call a new function creating new scope and executing line by line until it reaches Call#1 and the process starts again.

Comment: Unless `a==c` on the initial call, in which case `a==b` on the first recursive call, which will return, but then you're back to calling the original method with the exact same parameters, which depending on whether tail recursion optimization is available or not will either crash or run indefinitely.

Comment: i think it will cause crash

Comment: Yes, eventually it will crash, when the stack is overflown. 
When a==c and a!=b then call 2 can be executed.